# Is it possible to use facets and repeat operator for histograms?

Tags: vega-lite

I want to combine facet operators (row, column) along with the repeat operator to create 'small multiple' charts that display different data variables. This works for some types of charts (e.g. simple bar charts) but not others (i.e. histograms). For example, below I have modified the 'Horizontally repeated charts' example (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/repeat_histogram.html).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "repeat": {"column": ["Horsepower","Miles_per_Gallon", "Acceleration"]},
  "spec": {
    "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
      "row":{"field":"Origin", "type":"nominal"},
      "x": {
        "field": {"repeat": "column"},
        "bin": true,
        "type": "quantitative"
      },
      "y": {"aggregate": "count","type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }
}
```

I expect three rows, with each row showing histograms of cars from different countries. However, this code results in the error :

```
'Error: Undefined data set name: "scale_child_Miles_per_Gallon_child_main"'
```

I'm reasonably sure that this worked with Vega-Lite v2. Is there some reason that the aggregate / bin operator can't work with a combination of facets and repeats?

Comment: This is definitely a bug -- I've filed an issue -- https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4450.  

In the future, please feel free to file an issue on Github if you run into a runtime error that does not make sense. (This run time error is a Vega error.)

Comment: thanks, will do. I wasn't sure what the divide was between slack / stackoverflow / github.

Comment: No problem at all.  If you have a usage question (how to do something), please use stack overflow.   If you're confident that something is a bug, you can file an issue directly on Github.  (Feel free to ask on SO/Slack if you're not sure.)